# Laravel with URL issues

Tags: laravel, routes

I need help with Laravel.

My website has multiple URLs for the same pages. The URL includes category-subcategory-product but the URL include: double slash category//product or category//subcategory/product and all they link to the same page.
I asked a developer he said not sure but it maybe from route issue-URL not setup correctly. 
Has anyone come across with such issue? What's the main problem and how can I fix it quickly?

Comment: can you please provide some relevant code please

Comment: There are potentially quite a few reasons that this would be happening. Without seeing some code i.e. how the urls are generated or how they're added to the page etc., it's going to be very hard for someone to be able to help you.

Comment: Here are some examples of the URLs https://www.mycharitymarketplace.com/people/gifts-for-her/daughter
https://www.mycharitymarketplace.com/people//daughter
https://www.mycharitymarketplace.com/people//gifts-for-her/daughter

Comment: hope this can help you understand the issue

Comment: Include the code into your question. This helps other people.

Comment: for this page  https://www.mycharitymarketplace.com/people//daughter  the breadcrumbs shows this > People > > Daugther

Comment: So what code do you need? which part?

Comment: Rouhollah Mazarei plz answer to my question